# Player movement vs world movement in infinite runner game?

Tags: unity, android, 3d

Well I'm developing a Temple Run or Subway Surfer style infinite runner game. Which is more good? -Moving the player and make the Main Camera follow, or keep the player in one position and move the generated worlds? And the generated paths or worlds will have many animations in it. So which choice ouuld be good and why?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the camera stationary and move the world. The moving-camera setup has a lot of disadvantages for games of this genre.

When the player plays for a long time, the player-character moves further and further away from the scene origin. The further you move away, the less accurate do floating point numbers become. That can cause some very weird glitches to appear after a while. Depending on how fast the character is moving and how long the average playsession takes, there is a chance that this problem will never actually become relevant in practice. But you never know.

Then you will have a lot of game-objects which will always keep their position relative to the camera. Among these are the obstacle-spawner(s) at the far edge of the screen and the despawn collider just behind the player which removes the obstacles when they leave the screen. With a stationary-camera setup, these objects won't move either. That means you can set these objects as static, which will improve the performance of the collision detection system.

The moving-player setup also has a practical disadvantage for your development workflow. When you testplay your game in the Unity editor, the camera on the game-window will follow the player-character but the camera in the editor-window will not. If you want to know whats happening, you need to pause the game, switch to the editor and try to find the position of the player. In the stationary-player setup, you can just orient the camera in your editor to always keep the playfield in view while you testplay.

The only disadvantage of a stationary-camera setup I could think of is that rigidbody physics might not behave as expected in that setup. But very few games of that genre make use of that. Still, if you want to have rigidbody physics in your infinite runner, then a moving-camera setup might give you better results.

Comment: "The only disadvantage of a stationary-camera setup I could think of is that rigidbody physics might not behave as expected in that setup. But very few games of that genre make use of that. Still, if you want to have rigidbody physics in your infinite runner, then a moving-camera setup might give you better results."

Comment: There will be many obstacles. So i think by "rigid body physics" did you mean the collisions etc?

Comment: @Prakash [Rigidbody physics](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/rigidbodies) is the Unity Newtonian physics engine. You can use it to make objects fly around in physically correct trajectories when they ram into each other. I could, for example, imagine an infinite runner where the player-character runs into a wall of boxes and those boxes then tumble around the track. I have no idea if you want to do something like that or not.

Comment: So bro what do i do? ?

Comment: Move player or world?

Comment: @Prakash I can not tell you what to do because I don't know your game. I listed some advantages and disadvantages. How much these apply to your particular game is for you to decide.